# Trigger an event when close button is clicked in datepicker

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker, mouseevent

I would like to know if there is anyway to trigger an event , when close button is clicked in Datepicker calendar widget? I want to set a flag when the close button is clicked .

Comment: which datepicker? jquery-ui datepicker?

Comment: Yes. jquery-ui datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You have event called on close for jquery datepicker in which you can set your flag

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose

```
 $("selector").datepicker({
      onClose: function(selectedDate) {
       //set flag
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of onClose . But this works also when we press tab key in the keyboard ,which I don't want. I just want a function to be triggered only when I click close button on the buttonpanel of Datepicker.